# Setting "count" based on the length of an attribute on another resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a fairly simple Terraform configuration, which creates a Route53 zone and then creates NS records in Cloudflare to delegate the subdomain to that zone.  At present, it assumes there's always exactly four authoritative DNS servers for every Route53 zone, and creates four separate `cloudflare_record` resources, but I'd like to generalise that, partially because who knows if AWS will start putting a fifth authoritative server out there in the future, but also as a "test case" for more complicated stuff in the future (like AWS AZs, which I *know* vary in count between regions).

What I've come up with so far is:

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "public-zone-ns" {
  domain = "example.com"
  name   = "${terraform.env}"
  type   = "NS"
  ttl    = "120"
  count  = "${length(aws_route53_zone.public-zone.name_servers)}"
  value  = "${lookup(aws_route53_zone.public-zone.name_servers, count.index)}"
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "public-zone" {
  name = "${terraform.env}.example.com"
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` over this, though, I get this error:

```
Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* cloudflare_record.public-zone-ns: cloudflare_record.public-zone-ns: value of 'count' cannot be computed
```

I *think* what that means is that because the `aws_route53_zone` hasn't actually be created, terraform doesn't know what `length(aws_route53_zone.public-zone.name_servers)` is, and therefore the interpolation into `cloudflare_record.public-zone-ns.count` fails and I'm screwed.

However, it seems surprising to me that Terraform would be so inflexible; surely being able to create a variable number of resources like this would be meat-and-potatoes stuff.  Hard-coding the length, or creating separate resources, just seems so... limiting.

So, what am I missing?  How can I create a number of resources when I don't know in advance how many I need?

Comment: Currently count not being able to be calculated is an open issue in terraform https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12570

Comment: Thanks for the bug reference, @strongjz.  "computed" is the keyword I think I was missing in my searching.  I think this is *the* answer, at least for now.  Happy to upvote+accept if you'd like to make it a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently count not being able to be calculated is an open issue in terraform https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12570

You could move the name servers to a variable array and then get the length of that, all in one terraform script.

Answer (score 1):

I got your point, this surprised me as well. Even I added `depends_on` to resource `cloudflare_record`, it is helpless.

What you can do to pass this issue is to split it into two stacks and make sure the route 53 record is created before cloudflare record.

#### Stack #1

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "public-zone" {
  name = "${terraform.env}.example.com"
}

output "name_servers" {
  value = "${aws_route53_zone.public-zone.name_servers}"
}
```

#### Stack #2

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "route53" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    bucket = "terraform-state-prod"
    key    = "network/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "public-zone-ns" {
  domain = "example.com"
  name   = "${terraform.env}"
  type   = "NS"
  ttl    = "120"
  count  = "${length(data.terraform_remote_state.route53.name_servers)}"
  value  = "${element(data.terraform_remote_state.route53.name_servers, count.index)}"
}
```

Comment: Hoo boy, that's quite the workaround.  Will implementing that require two separate `terraform plan/apply` runs to complete the setup?

Comment: Yes. Normally I build the terraform stacks with several layers, such as network(vpc), database, applications, and route53/cloufront, etc. Now, you need to add one more layer on top of route 53 stack.